# Converting extended ASCII string to hindi text

Tags: java, conventions, extended-ascii

I am receiving a string text via USB communication in android in form of extended ASCII characters like

```
String receivedText = "5286T11É¬ ªË ¦¿¯¾ ¯¾ É¬ ¨¬°:A011605286 ª¿ª ¾®:12:45 ¸Í®°:(9619441121)ª¿ª:-, ®¹¿¦Í°¾ ¡ ®¹¿¦Í°¾ ª¨À, ¾¦¿µ²À ¸Í, ¾¦¿µ²À ªÂ°Íµ °¿®¾°ÍÍ¸:- ¡Í°Éª:-, ¬¾¹°, ¸¾¤¾Í°Â¼ ªÂ°Íµ~";
```

Now these character represents a string in hindi.

I am not getting how to convert this received string into hindi equivalent text.
Any one knows how to convert this into equivalent hindi text using java

Following is the piece of code which I am using to convert byte array to byte string

```
public String byteArrayToByteString(byte[] arayValue, int size) {
        byte ch = 0x00;
        int i = 0;

        if (arayValue == null || arayValue.length <= 0)
            return null;

        String pseudo[] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
                "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();

        while (i < size) {

            ch = (byte) (arayValue[i] & 0xF0); // Strip off high nibble
            ch = (byte) (ch >>> 4); // shift the bits down
            ch = (byte) (ch & 0x0F); // must do this is high order bit is on!
            out.append(pseudo[(int) ch]); // convert the nibble to a String
            // Character
            ch = (byte) (arayValue[i] & 0x0F); // Strip off low nibble
            out.append(pseudo[(int) ch]); // convert the nibble to a String
            // Character
            i++;
        }
        String rslt = new String(out);

        return rslt;
    }
```

Let me know if this helps in finding solution

**EDIT:**

Its an UTF-16 encoding and the characters in receivedText string is in form of extended ASCII for hindi characters

**New Edit**

I have new characters

```
String value = "?®Á?Ç¶ ¡??°¿¯¾";
```

Which says मुकेश in hindi and dangaria in hindi. Google translator is not translating dangaria in hindi so I cannot provide you hindi version of it.

I talked to the person who is encoding he said that he removed 2 bits from the input before encoding i.e. if \u0905 represents अ in hindi then he removed \u09 from the input and converted remaining 05 in extended hexadecimal form.

So the new input string I provided you is decoded in form of above explanation. i.e. \u09 is been removed and rest is converted into extended ascii and then sent to device using USB.

Let me know if this explanation helps you in finding out solution

Comment: If it is a Java String, it is Unicode (UTF-16.) If it is anything else, it is a corrupted string. Show how you convert the bytes from the device into strings.

Comment: Actually this string is received from a hardware which they are using to show hindi text and I think its a UTF-16 text but I do not know how to convert it. I received it in form of byte array and then I convert this into string

Comment: you could also create your own local object, and work with it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html

Comment: Ok but how can I work with the above received string?

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya Use a [String constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) that lets you specify the encoding (charset) or use an `InputStreamReader` with the same if receiving data from an `InputStream`.

Comment: @KevinEsche Java's `Locale` type does not influence text encoding.

Comment: I used string constructor new String(byte,"UTF-16") and the output is 㔲㠶吱㇂鳃观갠슆슪슕쎋⃂ꛂ뿂꿂븠슗슯슾⃂鳃观갠슨슂슬슰㩁〱ㄶ〵㈸㘠슪슿슕슅슪⃂鿂뻂蟂긺ㄲ㨴㔠슕슸쎍슟슮슰㨨㤶ㄹ㐴ㄱ㈱⧂ꫂ뿂闂藂꨺⴬⃂껂맂뿂苂ꛃ跂냂븠슏슂슡⃂껂맂뿂苂ꛃ跂냂븠슕슂슪슨쎀Ⱐ슕슾슂슦슿습슲쎀⃂蟂룃跂鼬⃂闂뻂苂ꛂ뿂뗂닃耠슪쎂슰쎍습⃂냂뿂껂뻂냃跂闃跂렺ⴠ슡쎍슰쎉슪㨭Ⱐ슬슾승슰Ⱐ슸슾슂스슾슕쎍슰쎂슜슼⃂꫃苂냃跂땾 :(

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya If you are sure it is UTF-16, perhaps it does not use network byte order. See [UnicodeBigUnmarked vs UnicodeLittleUnmarked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html).

Comment: Can you show what the received string should actually be like? This would make it easier to find a conversion leading from one to the other.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski I have posted it above in my question. its receivedText . Please check that out

Comment: I think @MichałKosmulski wanted to see what the characters should be after conversion. Is that something you can provide?

Comment: @laz please check my new edit

Comment: That doesn't help me too much. What are the raw byte values that are supposed to be re-encoded to `मुकेश`?

Comment: yes they have to be re-encoded to मुकेश

Comment: Any solutions? Any one?

Comment: What is creating the `String`? Is it possible to work with the raw bytes produced by the USB connection? I'm still not sure I understand what encoding the data from the USB connection is in. You mention truncating the bytes which seems like it would lead to data loss. You also mention encoding in extended ASCII. Does that mean ISCII or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, for a byte array that you know to be a **string value**, you can use the following.

Assuming `byte[] someBytes`:

```
String stringFromBytes = new String(someBytes, "UTF-16");
```

You may replace "UTF-16" with the approprate charset, which you can find after some experimentation. This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) detailing java's supported character encodings may be of help.

From the details you have provided I would suggest considering the following:

- If you're reading a file from a USB drive, android might have existing frameworks that will help you do this in a more standard way.
- If you most certainly need to read in and manipulate the bytes from the USB port directly, make sure that you are familiar with the API/protocol of the data you are reading. It may be that some of the bytes are control messages or something similar that cannot be converted to strings, and you will need to identify exactly where in the byte stream the string begins (and ends).

Comment: I have tried this thing but yet not succeeded to convert it into hindi

Comment: Are you sure that the whole byte array is the string data? I'm not familiar with the USB communication protocol, but maybe the array includes extra protocol related bytes?
If it is only string data, and you have tried all Java's standard charsets, then it would indicate to me that the string has a less standard encoding, and you would have to dig up some information from your specifications as to what this encoding might be.

Comment: I receives receivedText(String from my question) in form of byte array. and I tried to convert it in form that you have written in your answer. But still no output.

Comment: Can you provide the signature of the method you used to receive the byte array?

Comment: int com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialDriver.read(byte[] arg0, int arg1) throws IOException

Comment: I'll need to double check the type of UsbSerialDriver, but I would look for a solution where you wrap it as an input stream and acquire a string from it.

Comment: I do not use input stream as because this read method of UsbSerialDriver returns me byte array and response of it is int.

Comment: I have modified my answer above to describe how I would use the Android USB Host API to read a string from a USB device.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25070/discussion-between-erik-madsen-and-abhinav-singh-maurya)

Comment: I discussed with a colleague who's more familiar with Android and added the advice he gave above.

Comment: also, I updated the link with encodings to the java 6 version.

Comment: Check the chat Erik in the previous chat discussion

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing around with this a bit and have an idea of what you might need to do. It looks like the value for `receivedText` that you have in your posting is encoded in `windows-1252` for some reason. It was probably from pasting it into this post perhaps. Providing the raw byte values would be better to avoid any encoding errors. Regardless, I was able to get that `String` into the following Unicode Devanagari characters:

```
5286T11फए ऋभ इडऒठ ऒठ फए उएओ:A011605286 ऋडऋ ठऍ:12:45 चयऍओ:(9619441121)ऋडऋ:-, ऍछडइयओठ ँ ऍछडइयओठ ऋउढ, ठइडगऑढ चय, ठइडगऑढ ऋतओयग ओडऍठओययच:- ँयओफऋ:-, एठछओ, चठअठयओतञ ऋतओयग~
```

With the following code:

```
final String receivedText = "5286T11É¬ ªË ¦¿¯¾ ¯¾ É¬ ¨¬°:A011605286 ª¿ª ¾®:12:45 ¸Í®°:(9619441121)ª¿ª:-, ®¹¿¦Í°¾ ¡ ®¹¿¦Í°¾ ª¨À, ¾¦¿µ²À ¸Í, ¾¦¿µ²À ªÂ°Íµ °¿®¾°ÍÍ¸:- ¡Í°Éª:-, ¬¾¹°, ¸¾¤¾Í°Â¼ ªÂ°Íµ~";

final Charset fromCharset = Charset.forName("x-ISCII91");
final CharBuffer decoded = fromCharset.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(receivedText.getBytes("windows-1252")));

final Charset toCharset = Charset.forName("UTF-16");
final byte[] encoded = toCharset.encode(decoded).array();
System.out.println(new String(encoded, toCharset.displayName()));
```

Whether or not those are the expected characters is something you would need to tell me :)

Also, I'm not sure if the `x-ISCII91` character encoding is available in Android.

Comment: Your solution looks quite likely to be correct (even though I don't know Hindi by any means). I was looking for a charset which would provide the string in question when decoded using the default encoding instead of the correct one, but it looks you bet me to it. Cheers!

Comment: Very nice try @laz, the characters are in hindi but the output is not correct i.e. the output is not in correct hindi. I am upvoting for your efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

```
hindi = new String(receivedText.getBytes(), "UTF-16");
```

But this does not really look like hindi.. are you sure it is encoded as UTF-16?

**Edit:**

```
String charset = "UTF-8";
hindi = new String(hindi.getBytes(Charset.forName(charset)), "UTF-16");
```

Replace UTF-8 with the actual charsed that resulted in your loooong String.

Comment: But the way in general will work. Find out which Charset resulted in your **receivedText**, then extract the bytes from your text using that Charset, then make a new String from that bytes and use a proper encoding (may be UTF-16).

Comment: @MarcMosby the proposal to encode the corrupted string as UTF-8 and decode it as UTF-16 is not likely to work. The data is already corrupt. These transcoding operations are often destructive as illegal or unsupported sequences are converted to the replacement character.

Comment: try setting the system encoding to `utf-16`: 

`System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-16")`;